# How to install Windows 8.1 on a computer having Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

I had Windows 8 on my computer and I upgraded it to Windows 10. Now I want to revert back to Windows 8.1. I have Windows 8.1 but the setup gives me the following error,

```
Something happened.
```

Please guide me how can I install Windows 8.1 on a computer having Windows 10?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIj1H_6R7-k

Comment: You have formatted the HDD and booted to the installation media?  We really need more information.

Comment: @Ramhound: No. I have installed it over Windows 8.1 using the setup.

Comment: You will need W8 install or factory recovery media since it has been more than 30 days. Do a clean install by booting from the Installation media, select Advanced install, then delete all old partitions before continuing with install.

Answer (score 0):

### Go Back to Windows 8.1

If you’ve upgraded a PC to Windows 10 — not performed a clean install, but an upgrade — you’ll have an easy option that lets you revert to the last version of Windows. To access this, open the **Start** menu and select **Settings**. Click the “**Update & security**” icon and select “**Recovery**.”

You should see a *“Go back to Windows 7”* or *“Go back to Windows 8.1”* option. Click the Get started button to get rid of your Windows 10 install and restore your previous Windows install. Microsoft will ask you why you want to go back.

[image]

### Note

If it’s been over a month — or if you’ve ran the Disk cleanup tool and removed the “Previous Windows installations” files or deleted the C:\Windows.old folder by hand — you’ll no longer see this option. Windows 10 appears to automatically remove the old Windows installation files after a month to free up space.

Comment: I think its been more than a month. I can't find this option there. Thanks.